# downsaling from coarse to high resolution climate data for a future projection dataset

Tags: python, calendar, interpolation, resolution

I have downloaded scenario ssp126 dataset from GCM INM-CM4-8. It is from year 2015 to 2100. It was global data and I cut it down to only cover Bangladesh area. The data has grid size 2x1.5 which makes a resolution of about 100km. I want to convert it into a higher resolution.

Here is the description of the dataset:

```
Dimensions:    (time: 1032, bnds: 2, lat: 5, lon: 3)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) object 2015-01-16 12:00:00 ... 2100-12-16 12:00:00
  * lat        (lat) float64 20.25 21.75 23.25 24.75 26.25
  * lon        (lon) float64 88.0 90.0 92.0
    height     float64 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) object ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, bnds) float64 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    tasmax     (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

To interpolate it to a high resolution, I downloaded a high resolution data (ERA5 reanalysis) which has grid size 0.1x0.1 making it about 10 km resoltion. It is from 2015 t 2022 so that it may overlap with the other data for these years.
Here is the description of this dataset:

```
Dimentions: time: 96, lat: 61, lon: 45
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-01-01 2015-02-01 ... 2022-12-01
    realization  int64 ...
  * lat          (lat) float64 20.34 20.44 20.54 20.64 ... 26.14 26.24 26.34
  * lon          (lon) float64 88.01 88.11 88.21 88.31 ... 92.21 92.31 92.41
Data variables:
    t2m          (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

I am trying to apply bilinear interpolation for changing the resolution
Here is the code that I tried:

```
#INM-CM4-8 (coarse resolution)
coarse_dataset = xr.open_dataset('D:\\Vandita\\RRU\\NSAB\\projection_data\\Bangladesh\\SSP126\\Bangladesh_subset.nc')

#ERA5 (High resolution)
ref_dataset = xr.open_dataset('D:\\Vandita\\RRU\\NSAB\\projection_data\\Bangladesh\\ERA5\\2015_to_2022_max_temp.nc')

# variable of interest (max temp)
coarse_tasmax = coarse_dataset['tasmax']
ref_t2m = ref_dataset['t2m']

# coordinates
coarse_lat = coarse_dataset['lat'].values
coarse_lon = coarse_dataset['lon'].values
ref_lat = ref_dataset['lat'].values
ref_lon = ref_dataset['lon'].values

# The calender format of the datasets is different so so we have to try and match it
coarse_time = coarse_dataset['time'].values
coarse_time_converted = [cftime.Datetime360Day.strptime(str(t), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in coarse_time]

# Empty array for the interpolated values
interp_tasmax = np.empty((len(ref_dataset['time']), len(ref_lat), len(ref_lon)))


for t_idx in range(len(ref_dataset['time'])):
    for lat_idx in range(len(ref_lat)):
        for lon_idx in range(len(ref_lon)):
            coarse_values = coarse_tasmax[t_idx, lat_idx:lat_idx+2, lon_idx:lon_idx+2].values.flatten()
            coarse_points = np.meshgrid(coarse_lat[lat_idx:lat_idx+2], coarse_lon[lon_idx:lon_idx+2])
            
            # Perform bilinear interpolation
            interp_tasmax[t_idx, lat_idx, lon_idx] = griddata(coarse_points, coarse_values,
                                                              (ref_lat[lat_idx], ref_lon[lon_idx]),
                                                              method='linear')

# New xarray dataset to store the interpolated values
interp_dataset = xr.Dataset({'tasmax': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], interp_tasmax)},
                            coords={'time': ref_dataset['time'],
                                    'lat': ref_dataset['lat'],
                                    'lon': ref_dataset['lon']})

# Update the time coordinate with the converted time values
interp_dataset['time'].values = ref_dataset['time'].values

# Save the interpolated dataset to a new netCDF file
interp_dataset.to_netcdf('high_res_tasmax.nc')
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 37
     34             coarse_points = np.meshgrid(coarse_lat[lat_idx:lat_idx+2], coarse_lon[lon_idx:lon_idx+2])
     36             # Perform bilinear interpolation
---> 37             interp_tasmax[t_idx, lat_idx, lon_idx] = griddata(coarse_points, coarse_values,
     38                                                               (ref_lat[lat_idx], ref_lon[lon_idx]),
     39                                                               method='linear')
     41 # New xarray dataset to store the interpolated values
     42 interp_dataset = xr.Dataset({'tasmax': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], interp_tasmax)},
     43                             coords={'time': ref_dataset['time'],
     44                                     'lat': ref_dataset['lat'],
     45                                     'lon': ref_dataset['lon']})

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_ndgriddata.py:264, in griddata(points, values, xi, method, fill_value, rescale)
    262     return ip(xi)
    263 elif method == 'linear':
--> 264     ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,
    265                               rescale=rescale)
    266     return ip(xi)
    267 elif method == 'cubic' and ndim == 2:

File interpnd.pyx:278, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator.__init__()

File interpnd.pyx:78, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase.__init__()

File interpnd.pyx:192, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd._check_init_shape()

ValueError: different number of values and points
```

I believe this error is because the number of lat and lon values do not match. But I cannot make them match. The area of interest is not a square shape. So I don't know how to proceed.